# pretty url from play.php?v=lorem-ipsum to play/lorem-ipsum

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url

I have this url:

```
example.com/play.php?v=lorem-ipsum
```

want it to be:

```
example.com/play/lorem-ipsum
```

here is my try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+play\.php\?v=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

result:

```
example.com/lorem-ipsum
```

so `play/` is missing
maybe because I have a folder named `play`

pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so play/ is missing.
> maybe because I have a folder named play

No, it is missing, because `$1` contains only the part you actually *captured* with your regular expression, the part inside the `(...)`.

You want `RewriteRule ^ /play/%1? [R=301,L,NE]` (unless you wanted the `play` part to also be dynamic, then you would have to capture whatever was in that place as well.)

> maybe because I have a folder named play

That *can* cause additional problems though, if you still have `MultiViews` activated, that should be deactivated in cases where you have such a partial overlap between "fake" URL, and actually existing files.

Comment: I tried `^ /play/%1? [R=301,L,NE]` and result is a blank page saying `Please, reload the page` - in Chrome

Comment: Well if `play/lorem-ipsum` does not physically exist - then you need to implement the "other direction", a rewrite _from_ `play/lorem-ipsum` to `play.php?v=lorem-ipsum`, as well. So that requesting this "fancy" URL actually triggers your play.php script, with the `lorem-ipsum` passed as value of the `v` parameter.

Comment: I tried hundred options and it works now, although I don't know how. Anyway thanks a lot